# How to access to the values stored in a flann::Matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, flann

I'm working with flann library with point clouds. I have this adapter method that transform my own points to a flann-usable points

```
flann::Matrix<float> * converterFlann::convertArray(vector<Point *> *P){

    float points[P->size()*3];

    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<P->size(); i++){

        points[j] = P->at(i)->getX(); j++;
        points[j] = P->at(i)->getY(); j++;
        points[j] = P->at(i)->getZ(); j++;
    }

    P->at(0)->print();
    cout << points[0] << " " << points[1] << " " << points[2] << endl;

    flann::Matrix<float> *nari = new flann::Matrix<float>(points, P->size(), 3);

    cout << *nari[0][0] << " " << *nari[0][1] << " " << *nari[0][2] << endl;

    return nari;
}
```

And the output of this method is

```
Printing my point:         (-0.06325,   0.0359793,  0.0420873) Index: 0
Printing from points array: -0.06325 0.0359793 0.0420873
Printing from flann:        -0.06325 -0.06275 -0.0645
```

I don't understand why printing from flann::Matrix, Y and Z are different. I've been looking for some documentation about storing procedure of flann::Matrix but I'm not able to find any answer. I thing that my array-type access is correct but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance. :D